# Flutter Git action bundler: failed to load command: pod

Tags: ios, flutter, continuous-integration, github-actions, cocoapods

I'm attempting to build and deploy an iOS app to TestFlight using Fastlane and GitHub Actions.

Here's the issue I'm encountering:

```
bundler: failed to load command: pod (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/bin/pod)
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:308:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable pod for gem cocoapods. cocoapods is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:336:in `block in replace_bin_path'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/bin/pod:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.8/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from
```

here  is my Git action code:

```
name: iOS TestFlight

on:
  push:
    branches: [fastlane_ios]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy-ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: "2.7"

      # Only if Flutter is required
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        if: ${{ needs.FlutterSetup }} # See 'Conditional Flutter Setup' below
        with:
          flutter-version: "3.16.2"
          channel: "stable"
          architecture: x64
          cache: true

      - name: Install CocoaPods dependencies
        run: |
          cd ios
          gem install cocoapods # Pre-install for path discovery
          which pod
          echo $(which pod) >> $GITHUB_PATH # Add pod's path to PATH  
          bundle install 
          bundle exec pod install

      - name: Build and Deploy to TestFlight
        env:
          APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID: "${{ secrets.APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID }}"
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_ID }}"
          DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER }}"
          DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID }}"
          FASTLANE_APPLE_ID: "${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_ID }}"
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}"
          MATCH_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}"
          GIT_AUTHORIZATION: "${{ secrets.GIT_AUTHORIZATION }}"
          PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER: "${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER }}"
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}"
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER: "${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER }}"
          APPLE_KEY_ID: "${{ secrets.APPLE_KEY_ID }}"
          APPLE_ISSUER_ID: "${{ secrets.APPLE_ISSUER_ID }}"
          APPLE_KEY_CONTENT: "${{ secrets.APPLE_KEY_CONTENT }}"
        run: |
          cd ios
          bundle exec fastlane closed_beta
```

When I reach the step "Install CocoaPods dependencies", it successfully runs and installs the gem. However, when it tries to run pod, I face issues.